# Why does cell.textLabel.text need an identifier?

Tags: ios, cell

I get an error `"Parse issue expected identifier"` by the compiler. I don't understand what is the problem. The cell has an identifier, and all I want is to retrieve a pointer to the label.

```
UITableViewCell  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
//UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *cellLabel = [cell.textLabel.text];
```

The line that I commented works, where `[cell viesWithTag:1]` retrieves the label with tag 1. But I wonder why the next line doesn't work the same way. The line:

```
UILabel *cellLabel = [cell.textLabel.text]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

These are two different uses of the word "identifier". The error has nothing to do with the cell identifier.

It looks like the syntax you want is:

```
UILabel *cellLabel = cell.textLabel;
```

What you had instead was just part of an Objective-c message expression:

`[someObject someMessage] // send someMessage to someObject`

where `someObject` in your case was the `cell.textLabel.text` (an NSString*), but you didn't include the `someMessage`, which is the identifier the compiler was looking for there.

But, again, it sounds like you really just wanted to read the `textLabel` property of your cell, which is just `cell.textLabel` or `[cell textLabel]`.